# Discontinuity of the Fourier transform of $ x \mapsto (1+ x^2)^{- \gamma/2}$ for $\gamma \leq 1$

Tags: differential-operators, fourier-transform, continuity, green-function

Fix $\gamma > 0$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the Fourier transform and consider the function
$f(x) = (1+ x^2)^{- \gamma/2}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This function is in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ and its Fourier transform is well-defined.

Clearly, $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ for $\gamma > 1$, hence $\mathcal{F}\{f\}$ is continuous in this case.

**Question:** Can we show that $\mathcal{F}\{f\}$ is **not** continuous for $0 < \gamma \leq 1$?

*Context:* $f$ is Fourier transform of the Green's function of the Bessel potential operator $(\mathrm{Id} - \Delta)^{\gamma / 2}$. I need to understand when is the Green's function continuous. I have the same question in higher dimension for the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = (1+ \|x\|^2)^{- \gamma/2}$: Is the Fourier transform of $f$ continuous if and only if $\gamma > n$?

Comment: The Fourier transform $F(t)$ of $f(x)$ diverges at $x=0$ as $t^{\gamma-1}$ for $\gamma<1$. For $\gamma=1$ it equals $K_0(|t|)$, so it diverges as $\log|t|$.

Comment: To add some detail to Carlo's comment, $f=|x|^{-\gamma}+g$ with $g\in L^1$, and the FT of $|x|^{-\gamma}$ is $c|t|^{\gamma -1}$. For $\gamma=1$, you need to be more careful here since $|x|^{-1}$ is not a distribution, but you can regularize at $x=0$, and the FT diverges logarithmically. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137994/fourier-transform-of-xs-and-logx/4117943#4117943

Comment: Thank you to both of you, this solves my problem. By digging on Carlo's suggestion for $K_0$, I realise that the modified Bessel functions of the second kind are exactly the Fourier transform I am looking for.